# How can I find out if there is actually a cuda-toolkit-6-0 or similar in the apt-get repository (it should exist, but apt-get doesnt see it)?

Tags: apt, nvidia, cuda

On my NVidia Jetson TK1 I ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit-6-0
```

But got this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cuda-toolkit-6-0
```

In the [installation instructions on elinux.org](http://elinux.org/Jetson/Installing_CUDA), written by NVidia, they very clearly say to install cuda-toolkit-6-0.  What could be going on?  Can I search the apt-get repository for all packages containing the word "cuda"?  It seems odd that NVidia would mess up such a basic instruction, and I'm pretty sure people are using this machine explicitly for cuda applications.

The only difference from their instructions was when I downloaded cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2_6.0-42_armhf.deb, I allowed the Ubuntu Software Center to do the install instead of using sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2_6.0-42_armhf.deb.  I don't think that should be an issue though.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 14.10 you can install nvidia-331, NVIDIA CUDA toolkit and the NVIDIA CUDA 5.5 Runtime library directly from the default Ubuntu repositories. libcudart5.5 is the package name of the NVIDIA CUDA runtime library. libcudart5.5 requires the nvidia-331 or more recent graphics driver. There is also an NVIDIA CUDA toolkit package (nvidia-cuda-toolkit) in the default Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 14.10, and like libcudart5.5 it is also version 5.5.

In Ubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 15.10 libcudart5.5 has been upgraded to libcudart6.5, and the nvidia-cuda-toolkit like libcudart6.5 is also version 6.5.

In Ubuntu 16.04 libcudart has been upgraded to libcudart7.5, and the nvidia-cuda-toolkit like libcudart7.5 is also version 7.5.

Comment: on search in the software center i got two options for cuda toolkits.  i ended up getting cuda-toolkit-6-5 (~1gb).  the other option was cuda-minimal-build-6-5 (~40mb).

Comment: cuda-toolkit-6-5 and cuda-minimal-build-6-5 are not from the Ubuntu repositories. Either you have already installed them or you have added a third-party repository that has those two packages to your software sources. If so, you should remove that third-party repository using `sudo add-apt-repository -r <repo to remove> && sudo apt-get update` where you replace `<repo to remove>` with the name of the repository to be removed. After you have removed that third-party repository from your software sources, the Software Center will again show the CUDA packages from the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the instructions are outdated. They mention CUDA 6.0 and Ubuntu 12.04, whereas the [nVidia downloads page](https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1-support) mention CUDA 6.5 and Ubuntu 14.04. There's no evidence that the wiki page you link to is written by nVidia, so it's not a surprise to me.

Comment: Suggest adding a link to the official NVIDIA [Download CUDA Toolkit 6.5](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) webpage. CUDA Toolkit 6.5 has a new feature to allow you to develop or recompile your applications to run on 64-bit ARM systems with NVIDIA GPUs

Comment: @karel why? If it were relevant nVidia would have linked to that on the nVidia Jetson page.

Comment: Because the OP mentioned that he already downloaded cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2_6.0-42_armhf.deb the OP may also be interested in using CUDA with an ARM system, in which case the OP could install CUDA 6.5 from the official NVIDIA CUDA website.

Comment: @karel That's because OP is following outdated instructions. The link on https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1-support is  for `cuda-repo-l4t-r21.1-6-5-prod_6.5-14_armhf.deb`, a newer version.

Comment: This is constructive because it would be better for the OP to know what his requirements are before he starts to install and uninstall software. The Ubuntu CUDA Toolkit 6.5 installer packages from the official NVIDIA CUDA website include NVIDIA drivers, so if the OP has already installed the proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver from the Ubuntu Software Center, it would have to be uninstalled too beforehand.

Comment: @karel Sorry, but I must disagree. I don't see any need to mention the CUDA page at all. All I see is a need to update the instructions that OP was following.

Comment: OK sorry, I'll delete all my comments under your question if you delete yours, the whole purpose of which was to avoid potential confusion about CUDA rather than create it and it certainly was not intended as poaching on your answer.

Comment: @karel I don't see it as poaching. Let the comments remain, perhaps the OP or others can weigh in (and perhaps make me see what I am missing here).